# Vertical ViewPagers(kind of) thing using a list(recyclerview or listview)

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-recyclerview

What I want to achieve is that when the list is populated in recyclerview, every list item when scrolled up or down should be displayed as one item in the list only(covering whole of the space provided for the recyclerview). In other word, lets say that each list item should match the height and width of recyclerview. When the list is scrolled all the big listitems can be seen scolling but when scrolling ends only one view is displayed.

If still not clear, I just want a recyclerview to show only one item at a time and if we want to see other list items we have to scroll.

Similar to what a view pager but vertical in direction and should be using a recyclerview.